# Как подключить сертификат для доступа к почте gmail.com в Java

Tags: java

Разбираю учебный проект - работа с почтовым сервером gmail.com.
При запуске вылетела ошибка:

```
Failed receive: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

На этой сайте нашел инструкцию как подключить сертификат:
[PKIX path building failed” and “unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)

Все сделал по инструкции:

1. В хроме скачал сертификат с этого сайта, сохранил в файл mgmail.cer
2. Подключил его командой

   keytool -import -alias mgmail -keystore  c:\Development\Java\jdk11\lib\security\cacerts -file mgmail.cer
3. Перегрузил комп, но ошибка все равно остается
4. Проверяю командой

   keytool -list -trustcacerts -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit

сертификат есть в списке:

```
mgmail, 2 февр. 2021 г., trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 9A:63:32:BE:95:...
```

Что я упустил?
Скрин версии JDK:
[ver Java](https://pastein.ru/i/Sv)

Вот часть кода (тут я пробую читать с сервера mail.ru, там imap настроен по умолчанию), и все равно таже ошибка:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("src\\main\\resources\\config.properties");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(fileInputStream);
    String user = properties.getProperty("mail.user");
    String password = properties.getProperty("mail.password");
    String host = properties.getProperty("mail.host");

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    Store store = Session.getInstance(prop).getStore();
    store.connect(host, user, password);

    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    System.out.println("Кол-во сообщений" + inbox.getMessageCount());   
  }
```

файл config.properties

```
mail.user = name@mail.ru
mail.password = ...
mail.host = imap.mail.ru
```

Comment: Попробуйте указать путь и пароль к траст стору через систем пропертиз `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` и `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`. Есть пример [тут](https://www.webelement.click/ru/pkix_path_building_failed_in_api_tests_java)

Comment: не помогло. Теперь ошибка : "Failed receive: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)".  Я не понимаю почему приложение не видит файл cacerts, ведь там уже хранятся все основные сертификаты

Comment: Может среда разработки какой-то другой jre использует при запуске кода?

Comment: Проверил, JDK11. Скрин добавил. Вот только не пойму. Что там за путь странный. Знак ! после JDK11 стоит. От куда он его берет?

Comment: Странно, что Вам вообще приходится добавлять серт отдельно. По идее в дистрибуции jre вродят корневые сертификаты большинства сертификационных агенств. Попробуйте включить дебаг логирование ssl-соединений как показано [тут](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/973783). Может там будет подсказка.

Comment: Может быть проблема с почтовым ящиком ? Но я там уже все повключал, что бы ло в рекомендациях google

Comment: Попробуйте подготовить минимальный воспроизводимый пример, и добавьте его в вопрос.

Comment: Возможно, Вам надо добавить корневой сертификат (сертификат удостоверяющего центра).

Comment: Поясните, что вы имеете ввиду. Я зашел на mail.ru (я уже пробую с этим сервером) скопировал уже все три сертификата с этого сайта (все что там было). Это тоже не помогло

Comment: Покажи лог ошибки и лог запуска. Ибо я проверил на своем компьютере этот код и всё работает.

Comment: вот полный лог: https://pastein.ru/t/HF2

Comment: Вообще это немного странно. Вполне возможно, что тут антивирус подменяет сертификаты (у тебя винда). Достань сертификат через команду `openssl s_client -showcerts -servername imap.mail.ru -connect imap.mail.ru:993 </dev/null` и посмотри, что там. Правда надо сначала openssl установить.

Comment: Это просто капец. Отключил антивирус Avast и все заработало. Я бы ни когда не догадался. Нафига он так делает? Я не знаю как этот конкурс работает. Наверно тебе надо там что то сделать. Я подтверждаю, что твой совет помог в решении вопроса.

Comment: @Темкатоже, перенеси коммент в ответ

Answer (score 2):

Вообще это немного странно. Вполне возможно, что тут антивирус подменяет сертификаты (у тебя винда). Достань сертификат через команду openssl s_client -showcerts -servername imap.mail.ru -connect imap.mail.ru:993 </dev/null и посмотри, что там. Правда надо сначала openssl установить.

В качестве удостоверения в том, что виноват именно антивирус, отключи его и повтори попытку.

Подмена сертификатов делается для того, чтобы антивирус мог анализировать трафик. Т.е. трафик идёт сначала к антивирусу, а уже после к реальному хосту. Антивирусы обычно также заносят свои сертификаты в список доверенных для windows-хранилища, а также хранилищ браузеров при установке. А вот хранилище JRE они модифицировать ещё не научились.

Эта проблема гуглится по запросу [antivirus substitute https certificate](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=antivirus+substitute+https+certificate)

P.S. в Avast'e эту штуку можно отключить. См. [топик в форуме](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=190372.msg1335558#msg1335558)

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что проблема была в антивирусе (Avast). Как только его отключил все заработало. Спасибо за помощь в решении этого вопроса пользователю: **Темка тоже**. И всем остальным за участие